# What do I replace KeyCode with

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events, keycode

Im unsure how to replace e.keycode? should it be KeyBoardevent?

```
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, but if you're asking what to use instead of `keyCode` since `keyCode` is deprecated, the answer (you'll find this in the [MDN documentation for `keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)) is to use [`code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) (although [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) is also sometimes helpful, it depends on the use case).

Comment: "Im unsure how to replace e.keycode?" Why do you want to replace it? Because of a deprecation message?

Comment: Here is how to use with an enter press in an input, change it to whatever you want $(document).on("keypress", "input", function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
       // If enter is pressed on input, change to whatever //
    }
});